# Reduce the if-statement itself

Tags: c#, if-statement

This is my if-statement at the moment:

```
   if (excel_getValue("A" + i) == "" && 
    excel_getValue("A" + (i + 1)) == "" && 
    excel_getValue("A" + (i + 2)) == "" && 
    excel_getValue("A" + (i + 3)) == "" && 
    excel_getValue("A" + (i + 4)) == "" && 
    excel_getValue("A" + (i + 5)) == "" && 
    excel_getValue("A" + (i + 6)) == "" && 
    excel_getValue("A" + (i + 7)) == "" && 
    excel_getValue("A" + (i + 8)) == "")
```

Is there anyway I can reduce this statement? Should I build this if-statement in a for-loop?

BTW, this if-statement if already in a forloop and it uses the i of the forloop

Comment: Can you change the logic in excel_getValue or add another function?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use `All`:

```
if(Enumerable.Range(0, 9).All(c => excel_getValue("A" + (i + c)) == "")) {
}
```

Comment: You beat me to the linq part :-)

Comment: try using default functions like string.isNullOrEmpty() to check for an empty string

Answer (score 2):

There's an easy way to "reduce" (at least "beautify") with a `for` loop... this wouldn't be more performant though, so you choose:

```
bool do = true;
for(var j = 0; j < 9; j++) { 
   if (excel_getValue("A" + (i+j)) != "") {
     do = false;
     break;
   }
}
if(do) { /* whatever */ }
```

Or using Linq:

```
if(Enumerable.Range(0, 9).All(x => excel_getValue("A" + (i + x)) == "")) { /* whatever */ }
```

This could be probably reduced easily, but I guess the point is that it should be "prettier", and not "better" or "complicated". Nothing would beat your original one in terms of performance :-)

Comment: Not just prettier, but easier to read and understand after the fact, rather than having to check each term in the if for subtle differences.  Also the performance difference probably won't be noticeable by a user for most use cases.

Comment: @Paddy agreed, that's why I made the first "totally verbose" loop

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a `for` loop is a good way to simplify your code in this case. Something like:

```
   bool result = true;
   for(int j = 0; j < max; j++)
   {
      result = result && excel_getValue("A" + (i + j)) == "";
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
if (Enumerable.Range(0, 8).All(p => excel_getValue("A" + (i + p)) == ""))
```